# Android: Problem with Google Admob sample

Tags: android, admob

I'm trying to create a sample admob application with just the bare essentials. I followed the directions and even copied most of the code from this site: http://code.google.com/mobile/ads/docs/android/fundamentals.html, but the app keeps force closing on my VD and on my real device. The debugger gives a "RuntimeException" at the line: layout.addView(adview). I'm sure there is a simple solution to this, but I can't figure it out. I've searched around, but most of the information online is for pre-google admob - which used a different procedure.

Here is my MainActivity (my only Activity):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // Create the adView
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14dc6ed8aead31");
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.main);
    layout.addView(adView); //RuntimeException at this line
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    request.setTesting(true);
    adView.loadAd(request);
}
```

Heres my logcat error output:

05-22 17:49:24.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19619): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

05-22 17:49:24.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19619):     at com.example.admobsample.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:22)

05-22 17:49:24.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19619):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)

05-22 17:49:24.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19619):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)

05-22 17:49:24.534: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(19619):     ... 11 more

05-22 17:49:26.024: ERROR/PackageInstallationReceiver(17825): Remove /data/local/tmp/com.example.admobsample.apk Fail!

Comment: Whats yours Logcat error? I'm sure you have to set the adView's layout params (it's width and height);

Comment: I added it above.. Where do you set those parameters?

Comment: The logcat says your getting a NPE which is explained in @tg's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NPE happens because `layout` is `null`, i.e., there is no view with the ID `R.layout.main`.

Interpreting the original example

```
    // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it’s been given
    // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
```

you need to add the attribute `android:id` to your LinearLayout (the ID should be different from `R.id.main`).

Comment: Ok, that got it to run. Thanks... The banner didn't show up at first, but after about a minute, a sample ad popped up. Problem solved

Answer (score 2):

Once you fix your NPE error you may get a further error.

You have to set a layouts height and width before adding it to a view.

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14dc6ed8aead31");
adView .setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layoutMain);
layout.addView(adView);
```

Comment: setLayoutParams doesn't seem to effect anything - the program runs fine with and without it, and the ad banner looks the same in both cases